# How do you make NHibernate ignore a property in a POCO

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate-mapping

We have POCO, something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid PersonID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string   Version {get; set; }
}
```

And the corresponding hbm file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernate.FirstAttempt"  namespace="NHibernate.FirstAttempt.Entity" >
  <class name="Person" lazy="false">
    <id name="PersonID">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName"  />
    <property name="LastName"     />
    <property name="DateOfBirth"  />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If you look closely, we have a Version property, for which there is no column in the database ? We just want nHibernate to ignore this property and that's the reason we did not put the property in the mapping file. But instead it started throwing error.

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should make all members virtual and not map the property you want to ignore.

Comment: Was just wondering, is there a way out in case you don't want to make the members virtual ?

Comment: Yes, you have to disable lazy loading by default.  Then only collection properties need be virtual, IIRC.

Comment: @SanketNaik NHibernate uses Castle DynamicProxy internally and requires proxied class members to be virtual in order to intercept them.