# Fluent NHibernate ignore property inside the ClassMap, using FluentMappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 3.1 and Fluent NHibernate as ORM in my project. I need to have a property of a POCO ignored by Fluent NHibernate. At first, my post might look as exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907576/how-to-tell-fluent-nhibernate-not-to-map-a-class-property), but it is not.

My complications come first from the fact that the POCOs are defined in a different assembly than the mapping and I am using **fluent mappings** for my POCOs. I have additional requirement not to write ingore-property code where the session factory configuration takes place (this happens at a centralized place outside the modules), but as part of the module that defines the mappings. Ideally, I believe the right place would be the concrete `ClassMap` implementation, since it knows exactly how to describe a POCO to the ORM.

However, I am stuck on this mainly because this is my first impact with NHibernate and its fluent API. Up to now I am having very good impression of its capabilities and extensibility, and I hope there is a way to achieve my requirement in a way that the mapping related code is encapsulated in its corresponding module.

Here is my configuration, from a centralized place:

```
List<Assembly> assemblies = GetModules().Select(x => x.GetType().Assembly).ToList();

ISessionFactory nhibernateSessionFactory = Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Mappings(m => assemblies.ForEach(asm => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(asm)))
    .Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
            .ShowSql()
            .ConnectionString(DatabaseConfig.Instance.ConnectionString))
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaUpdate(c).Execute(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I use standard class mappings that inherit from `ClassMap`:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Username { get; set; }
    public virtual String Password { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    // Must ignore
    public string ComputedProperty  { get { ... } }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("User");
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(m => m.Username).Not.Nullable().Length(255).UniqueKey("User_Username_Unique_Key");
        Map(m => m.Password).Not.Nullable().Length(255);
        Map(m => m.DateCreated).Not.Nullable();
        Map(m => m.DateModified).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your mappings class look like and what does your configuration look like?

Comment: I revisited my question by adding some code

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830649/how-do-you-make-nhibernate-ignore-a-property-in-a-poco

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830649/how-do-you-make-nhibernate-ignore-a-property-in-a-poco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right that the `ClassMap` is the best place to ignore this property.

Example:

```
.Override<Shelf>(map =>  
{  
  map.IgnoreProperty(x => x.YourProperty);
});
```

Documentation: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#ignoring-properties

As far as getting the mappings from another assembly, it should be as easy as something like this (depending on your current configuration):

```
.Mappings(m =>
              {
                  m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ProvideClassFromYourOtherAssembly>();
              });
```

Comment: OK, but that way I need to know each class that must have a property ignored in the centralized initialization place, and have it explicitly configured. That is what I am trying to avoid. Imagine if I have to refactor a module, I must also modify the application ORM initialization too.

Comment: In your question, you say "I have additional requirement not to set ingoring the property in the session factory configuration (which happens at a centralized place) but as part of the module that defines the mappings." but now you are saying that this is the problem with my answer? Maybe I don't understand what you are asking, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I had a wrong impression that the overriding occurs at the centralized place where the session factory is being configured, my bad. The overrider interface can be put in the same assembly where I have defined my mapping.

Comment: -1. What are you calling `.Override` and `.Mappings` on? Besides, link is dead.

Comment: I've updated the dead link. Does that really merit a -1 for an accepted answer?  I'm not in control of other peoples websites, links die.  As for the examples, check the updated documentation link for a better context of what they are on - https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#ignoring-properties

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is not complete. Where should I put this override inside the `ClassMap`?

Comment: @rabejens the Override would go on the AutoMap like so: `AutoMap.AssemblyOf<ClassInYourAssembly>().Override<YourEntity>(...)`

Comment: @shanabus could you please point out what does `ClassInYourAssembly` mean in this context? Thank you

Comment: @ibanjo you want to replace `ClassInYourAssembly` with the name of a class that is inside the same assembly where your classes are that you want automapped. So looking at the original Question, you might choose to use `User`.  This allows the Assembly scanning to find other classes in the assembly and build auto mappings for them.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is bit old, but I post anyway since I didn't find any up todate posts on the subject.
I guess the easiest way should be to add an attribute to each property we dont want to be persisted to a table. By add a extension that check if it has for eg. has a [NoEntity] attibute.

```
/// <summary>
/// Tells a single Property to not be persisted to table.
/// </summary>
public class NoEntity : Attribute { }


    /// <summary>
/// Extension to ignore attributes
/// </summary>
public static class FluentIgnore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ignore a single property.
    /// Property marked with this attributes will no be persisted to table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">IPropertyIgnorer</param>
    /// <param name="propertyType">The type to ignore.</param>
    /// <returns>The property to ignore.</returns>
    public static IPropertyIgnorer SkipProperty(this IPropertyIgnorer p, Type propertyType)
    {
        return p.IgnoreProperties(x => x.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(propertyType, false).Length > 0);
    }
}
```

And in the fluent config setup:

```
            return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(DatabaseConfig)
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assembly(typeof(IDependency).Assembly)
            .OverrideAll(p => {
                p.SkipProperty(typeof(NoEntity)); 
            }).Where(IsEntity)))
            .ExposeConfiguration(ValidateSchema)
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildConfiguration();
```

Comment: Interesting approach! If only I did not have to keep my entities clean from ORM-related annotations (I have the mappings in a separate assembly, so I can reuse my entity classes from other assemblies without bringing any orm dependencies). I'll try to achieve the above effect via my mapping classes.

Comment: This will ignore any property that has any attributes on it at all. Probably not desired or expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Will not Justin. This is the thing with this extension. Just the property you want gets ignored.

```
public class Person : IEntity{ 
 public virtual string Name{..}
 public virtual string Lastname{..}

 [NoProperty]
 public virtual string FullName{ // Not created property
  get { return Name +  " " + Lastname;  }
 }
}

public class Group : IEntity{ 
 public virtual string FullName{..} //Created property
}
```